# Is there a technical limitation which requires redirect urls?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, tracking

A lot of services send your browser to another url when you click a link on their sites.
Google search results and links on Facebook would be two well-known examples.
The slower a connection, the more noticeable it is, when browsing on a mobile network, you can be looking at a blank page for seconds. During this time you can see the query string in the address bar, showing some of what is being logged.

I understand the reason for the redirects is so user-behaviour can be analysed, for any reason from service quality to target marketing, and that's fine. But why do we have to be sent to a different page? Is that not sub-optimal from the users perspective?

Could it not be handled by a javascript call instead? If not why not?

---

Edit: by using javascript I mean something like:

1. bind function to link
2. On click, have the function delay the redirect until the tracking query has been sent using ajax
3. Continue to page

Comment: Using JavaScript requires a page which doesn't get destroyed, so effectively you would need a main page with a frame. The main page could then log stuff while the actual page is loaded in the frame. But the URL in the address bar would stay at `google.com`.

Comment: Twitter's own image hosting service gets on my tits for this. The 3rd party ones aren't to bad but the Twitter one redirects you about 5 times which as you say can takes ages on mobile.

Comment: pimvdb, there are ways you can send the tracking query without needing iframes, I outlined a basic idea in my question after you made your comment to show what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that not sub-optimal from the users perspective?

Detailed user profiles are, apparently, more valuable than happy users.

> Could it not be handled by a javascript call instead? If not why not?

Browsers would leave the page before the request was sent with JavaScript and the data would be lost.

Comment: Can't you use javascript to wait until an AJAX query has been sent successfully before returning the link?

Comment: @puppybeard — You can't wait, although you could cancel the default behaviour and then set `location.href` afterwards … that wouldn't be any faster then the redirect approach though (you still have to wait for the HTTP response from the analytics server), and would be a lot more complicated.